# How do I find what GTK version is installed on Solaris?

Tags: eclipse, gtk, solaris

How do I find what version of GTK I have installed on a Solaris box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the header `gtkversion.h` and look what it defines:

```
$ grep "#define GTK_M.*_VERSION" /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/*
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkversion.h:#define GTK_MAJOR_VERSION           (2)
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkversion.h:#define GTK_MINOR_VERSION           (18)
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkversion.h:#define GTK_MICRO_VERSION           (3)
$
```

(where I've edited away some whitespace).

Comment: Doesn't that require knowing that you have gtk-2.0 already installed? ;-)

Comment: I know I had GTK 2.0 from the libraries in the /usr/lib folders.  I just couldn't find the versions but this worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the "pkg-config -modversion" command.  If you happen to have the (quite old at this point) gtk+ 1.2, there also used to be a gtk-config command as well.